# MPI_Isend to random destination

Tags: c, mpi

I'm having trouble getting MPI_Isend to send to a random destination.  If I hardcode the destination, it works fine, but if I try to generate a random one it does not.  Here is some relevant code:

```
    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&numprocs);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&myid);
    srand48(myid);
    request=MPI_REQUEST_NULL;
    if(myid == 0){
            buffer=drand48();
            do {
                    destination=lrand48() % numprocs;
            } while (destination == 0); //Prevent sending to self
            MPI_Isend(&buffer,1,MPI_DOUBLE,destination,1234,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&request);

    }
    else if (myid == destination) {
            MPI_Irecv(&buffer,1,MPI_DOUBLE,MPI_ANY_SOURCE,MPI_ANY_TAG,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&request);

    }
    if(myid == 0){
            printf("processor %d  sent %lf to %d\n",myid,buffer,destination);
    }
    else {
            printf("processor %d  got %lf\n",myid,buffer);
    }
```

I can compile just fine with `mpicc main.c`  When I run the program with `mpirun -np 4 ./a.out` the output is:

```
processor 0  sent 0.170828 to 2
processor 1  got 0.000000
processor 2  got 0.000000
processor 3  got 0.000000
```

If I hardcode the destination as 2, for instance, then I get the expected output:

```
processor 0  sent 0.170828
processor 1  got 0.000000
processor 2  got 0.170828
processor 3  got 0.000000
```

Comment: `destination` isn't set for any rank other than 0.  There's an excellent chance that no processor will ever execute the Irecv; and even if they do, you print the results before executing a Wait so there's no guarantee that the receive is complete at the time of output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MPI_Isend` and `MPI_Irecv` *initiate* the corresponding non-blocking operations. There is no guarantee that they will ever finish before you pass the returned `request` handle to a function from the `MPI_Wait` or `MPI_Test` families (if a test function is used, the completion state of the request is communicated back in a boolean variable and it is not complete as long as the boolean flag remains false).

There is a conceptual problem with your code though. MPI is a distributed memory paradigm - each MPI rank practically lives in its separate address space (although not strictly required by the standard, this is what virtually all MPI implementations provide). Hence setting `destination` in rank 0 does not transfer its value magically to the other processes. You could either broadcast that value first or send special "empty" messages to all other ranks, for example:

```
if (myid == 0) {
   MPI_Request reqs[numprocs];

   buffer=drand48();
   do {
      destination=lrand48() % numprocs;
   } while (destination == 0); //Prevent sending to self
   for (i = 1; i < numprocs; i++) {
      if (i == destination)
         MPI_Isend(&buffer,1,MPI_DOUBLE,i,1234,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&reqs[i]);
      else
         // Send an empty message with different tag
         MPI_Isend(&buffer,0,MPI_DOUBLE,i,4321,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&reqs[i]);
   }
   reqs[0] = MPI_REQUEST_NULL;
   MPI_Waitall(numprocs, reqs, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);     
   printf("processor %d  sent %lf to %d\n",myid,buffer,destination);
}
else {
   MPI_Status status;

   MPI_Recv(&buffer,1,MPI_DOUBLE,MPI_ANY_SOURCE,MPI_ANY_TAG,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
   if (status.MPI_TAG == 1234)
      printf("processor %d  got %lf\n",myid,buffer);
}
```

With broadcast the code would look like:

```
request=MPI_REQUEST_NULL;
if (myid == 0) {
   buffer=drand48();
   do {
      destination=lrand48() % numprocs;
   } while (destination == 0); //Prevent sending to self
   MPI_Bcast(&destination,1,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
   MPI_Isend(&buffer,1,MPI_DOUBLE,destination,1234,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&request);
}
else {
   MPI_Bcast(&destination,1,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
   if (myid == destination) {
      MPI_Irecv(&buffer,1,MPI_DOUBLE,MPI_ANY_SOURCE,MPI_ANY_TAG,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&request);
   }
}
MPI_Wait(&request, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
if (myid == 0) {
   printf("processor %d  sent %lf to %d\n",myid,buffer,destination);
}
else {
   printf("processor %d  got %lf\n",myid,buffer);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help-I understand now that setting the variable in the root process does nothing for that variable in the other processes.

Can you explain the need for the MPI_Bcast call in the else block?

Comment: @user2088217, `MPI_Bcast` is a collective operation - it must be called by all ranks in the communicator in order for it to complete. The originator of the data (the `root` rank in `MPI_Bcast`) cannot simply push it to the other ranks - they must do something to fetch it. `MPI_Bcast` does both the push and the fetch, but all ranks have to call it and all ranks have to specify the same `root` rank.